# Actual source code of CvCreateImage() function - OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv

Hii, I actually need to create a function similar to CvcreateImage() in OpenCV Library which can create an image of datatype other than IplImage (say Unsigned char or a structure like IplImage).
However, for this i need to know the source code of this function ( and others similar to it like CvReleaseImage() etc, basically functions with datatype CvAPI )
Can anyone please tell me how can i do this. Is there a way i can see the source code of these functions

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Download the source from their website:  http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

Comment: If you're simply trying to create an image with a different datatype use the `IPL_DEPTH_XX` flag.  The XX is replace by the number of bits and signed/unsigned/floating point.

`IPL_DEPTH_8U is equivalent to an unsigned char` ..
`IPL_DEPTH_16S is equivalent to a signed short` ..
`IPL_DEPTH_64F is equivalent to a double` ..
and so on and so forth...

Comment: Hii Steve and tbridge, actually I don't want to use any Opencv function but to write my own function with the similar functionality. Same goes with other functions like cvreleaseImage(), cvcreatemat(). Actually i want to see the source code of the functions which use CvAPI as return type.

Comment: Choose the appropriate source code according to your platform.

Answer (score 1):

**OpenCV is open source.**

[2.2 for *nix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.2/OpenCV-2.2.0.tar.bz2/download)

[2.2 for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.2/)

Answer (score 0):

See:
Opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp

Here you'll find actual code for cvCreateImage() function.